# Is it possible to obtain the shape of an IRL object from the slam algorithm to hide 3D objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to do some test with the AR in Unity, so my idea is to use the ground plane detection of the arcore to instantiate a ring. The ring is made of segments and I want to use an obstacle between the camera and some segment to hide these segments.

[image]

I have thought to use the slam to get the shape of the obstacle and use the coordinates to hide (disable or change shader/material) or not the segments behind the obstacle.

I do some researches about Vuforia and I know they use the slam but it does not seem that we can access the shape directly from Vuforia so I thought to use the arcore directly. I think it may be done with spatial mapping.

Because I am not very experienced I prefer to ask about the possibility to do it and if I am in the good way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the term you are looking for should be "Occlusion Management". Vuforia. There is a sample package in the asset store, but I don't know how much value it can offer to your cause. [Look here](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/packs/vuforia-rendering-sample-102252)

You could as well take a manual approach and integrate your obstacle as Image- or Model-Target, so that you can simply use a virtual replica of your obstacle that hides everything behind it. This however means that your obstacle would have to be always the same object, so I am not sure if this approach is suited for your needs. But this would be the easiest and cleanest way imho.

You can find many tips to get around occlusion problems [here](http://blog.guidigo.com/blog/how-to-work-around-occlusion-issues-in-augmented-reality/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The Vuforia Package looks like of what I need, but at first look it seems that it use predefine target for the obstacle. I am not sure I can use it to do occlusion with obstacle that I don't know the shape in advance.